# Need help with capacitor code

Tags: capacitor, identification, surface-mount

What are the specifics of this capacitor based on the code marking?

Where can I find replacements?

[image]

Comment: That’s not a capacitor but a transistor.

Comment: Even if you replace that transistor, it may still not work, if the transistor got damaged because a fault somewhere else, so the replacement can also damage immediately if the fault is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The Manufacturers Logo is International Rectifier, who's products are now part of Infineon.

From the attached picture the part number is FS300<last character unreadable>. Are you able to get a better picture to confirm the final character of the part number.

It **could** be a [IRFS3006 60V Single N-Channel HEXFET Power MOSFET in a D2-Pak package](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/n-channel/irfs3006/).

From the [IRFS3006 DataSheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFS3006-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356364a7a214f) the part marking format matches that on the device:

[image]

> Where can I find replacements?

As Justme said in a comment, you need to identify the failure mode, as otherwise if you replace the MOSFET could just get damaged again. What device is this from?

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is from a Magnum 2812 inverter/charger for my sailboat. The manual does not have an electronics diagram as they probably just want people to buy a new one and not fix it. How can I check what caused this? I was a shop teacher and licensed contractor for 25 years and understand the basics of electronics, but that’s about all. I did rewire my boat to AYBC standards, but that is pretty straight forward. Any help provided would be greatly appreciated. They said it would be fun to fix my boat in exotic ports. It has been so far!